# Disable Spring Boot Security @Secured at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'd like to disable @Security at runtime. I have annotated all my request mappings with @Secured({...}). By default these should be active but when the admin decides to disabled security these should not be protected.

I've tried using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure() and call something like

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
```

(depending on the configuration) but that doesn't help.

Any ideas? Perhaps it's possible to add the roles to an "anonymous" user? I checked the methos in HydraGlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration but didn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: The approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176236/disable-enableglobalmethodsecurity-annotation works.