# How to disable/ ignore @PreAuthorize in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I have a Spring Boot app that provides REST APIs. All the API are secured with Spring Security. I also have added method authorization using *@PreAuthorize* annotation.

For local development I would like to disable security altogether via a configuration or something. I want to disable both authentication and authorization so that I can easily call the APIs without having to acquire a fresh token each time I want to call the API.

Disabling Authentication is easy, I just added this to a config method and all good.

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/**");
}
```

But this causes **AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException** when hitting the endpoints that I excluded from authentication which makes sense. This exception goes away only when I remove the *@PreAuthorize* annotation which obviously I don't want to do whenever I'm about to do some local development work. It seems just by having the annotation on methods, Spring AOP kicks and checks for authentication object in Spring Security Context and there's no way to disable it rather than removing the annotations.

How can I get Spring to ignore *@PreAuthorize* annotations altogether? I tried removing *@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity* but it didn't help with the exception.

Comment: Do you override this method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception`? If so post everything from it in the question.

Comment: `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` is annotation which enables the scanning for `@PreAuthorize` annotations. If it is not present - `@PreAuthorize` annotations don't do anything.

Comment: @improbable that's what I also expected but when I removed EnableGlobalMethodSecurity PreAuthorize annotation was still getting scanned. At lease that AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException  was not going away for sure.

Comment: Post your whole security config.

Comment: @Vahid Removing `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` should work. Maybe there is another class with that annotation? However, you could find a better way in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176236/disable-enableglobalmethodsecurity-annotation

Comment: @dur you were right! there was `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` in a parent pom that I've been using and I think that was causing the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

I met the same problem, and I solved it with below code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Value("${security.enabled:true}")
  private boolean securityEnabled;


  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    if (!securityEnabled) {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }
  }

  /**
   * ommit codes
   */

  /**
   * control @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)，to  solve AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException
   */
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "security",
    name = "enabled",
    havingValue = "true")
  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
  static class Dummy {
  }
}
```

if `security.enabled=false`, `Dummy` bean will not be created, therefore `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` will also does not exist, and finally `@PreAuthorize` annotation will be ignored.

Comment: Excellent solution..searching for a day..finally found it..Thanks a million..